# Get URL from the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the URL from the Taskdescription tab and fetch it in other column with the name URL. Right now I am using this code

```
select 
     c.StreamName AS Category,
     ProcessInstanceAppianID as jobId,
     a.ProcessInstanceName,
     a.ProcessInstanceTargetDate AS TargetDate,
     a.ProcessInstanceDescription as TaskDescription,
     b.Name as department,
     SUBSTRING(ProcessInstanceName, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ProcessInstanceName),0),7) as code
from InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance a 
          join InternalUseOnly..Departments b on 
                          b.KeyDepartment = a.KeyDepartmentEntered 
                      AND b.updoperation < 2
           join InternalUseOnly..ProcessStream c on 
                          c.KeyProcessStream = a.KeyProcessStream 
                      and c.updoperation < 2
where ProcessInstanceCompleted is null
      and a.KeyProcessStream in (330) 
      and a.updoperation <2
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, then this will do the trick

```
SELECT substring(ProcessInstanceDescription , charindex('http://', ProcessInstanceDescription ), charindex('KeyInstr', ProcessInstanceDescription ) - charindex('http://', ProcessInstanceDescription ))
FROM InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58e71/1)

Let's just say I'm in a good mood today, here's the code you need. The URL will be in the first column.

```
select
     substring(a.ProcessInstanceDescription , charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ), charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ) - charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription )), 
     c.StreamName AS Category,
     ProcessInstanceAppianID as jobId,
     a.ProcessInstanceName,
     a.ProcessInstanceTargetDate AS TargetDate,
     a.ProcessInstanceDescription as TaskDescription,
     b.Name as department,
     SUBSTRING(ProcessInstanceName, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ProcessInstanceName),0),7) as code
from InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance a 
          join InternalUseOnly..Departments b on 
                          b.KeyDepartment = a.KeyDepartmentEntered 
                      AND b.updoperation < 2
           join InternalUseOnly..ProcessStream c on 
                          c.KeyProcessStream = a.KeyProcessStream 
                      and c.updoperation < 2
where ProcessInstanceCompleted is null
      and a.KeyProcessStream in (330) 
      and a.updoperation <2
```

**update:**

Regarding the `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` error, this means that you have somewhere in `ProcessInstanceDescription` column, a row that doesn't fit the format for my `SUBSTRING()`.

Good luck finding it as this is another question and I am not going to give you the solution to it, first of all because information is insufficient and your are not cooperative and apparently unwilling to do some effort yourself.

Comment: Can you please insert these lines into my query so that I can know where exactly do you place this and acheive what I want

Comment: @Anoop I gave you the answer, you should integrate it wherever you want in your query. Basically I did all the job for you by writing this query, you should be able to do this **very very basic** operation of **COPY-PASTING** yourself.

Comment: I agree with you but it is a very sensitive code so I don't want it to spoil. So please help me with this and add the query into the other query so that I can work accordingly. I realyy appreciate your help

Comment: I am getting this error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."
Can you please help me

Comment: @Anoop If I was the OP I would tell you to do some work for yourself. He's already gone beyond the call of duty to help you. Get out there and earn your salary on your own! since it's sensitive stuff, make a backup and try. Keep in mind that what I'd really want to tell you shouldn't be posted in this fine community. "Can you please help me?" - HE ALREADY DID THAT, a lot too.

Comment: I have not got the exact result what I want if you would help me on this it would be great